# Why aren't Rails model attributes accessible using symbols instead of strings?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, attributes, symbols

I need to compare some Rails (2.3.11) model attribute values before and after a database update, so I start by finding my record and saving the existing attribute values in a hash, as follows:

```
id = params[:id]
work_effort = WorkEffort.find(id)

ancestor_rollup_fields = {
    :scheduled_completion_date => work_effort.scheduled_completion_date
}

work_effort.update_attributes(params.except(:controller, :action))
#etcetera
```

Note I am adhering to the "best practice" of using a symbol for a hash key.

Then I have a method that takes the model and the hash to determine possible additional steps to take if the values from the hash and the model attributes don't match.  To determine this I tried to get at the model attribute value in an each loop but I was getting nil at first:

```
def rollup_ancestor_updates(work_effort, ancestor_rollup_fields)
    ancestor_rollup_fields.each do |key, value|
        model_val = work_effort.attributes[key] #nil
        #etcetera
```

In debugging the above I noticed that hard-coding a string as a key:

```
work_effort.attribute['scheduled_completion_date']
```

Returned the desired value.  So then in my each block I tried the following and it worked:

```
model_val = work_effort.attributes[key.to_s]
```

Is there a different way to do this?  To me, with just 3 months Ruby/Rails experience, it's confusing to use symbols as hash keys as is the prescribed best practice, but then have to call .to_s on the symbol to get at a model attribute.  Has anybody else experienced this, worked around this, been confused by this too?  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The Hash returned when you call `#attributes` on a AR instance has string keys, which is why a symbol as an index into the hash doesn't work in your case.  There is a subclass of `Hash` called `HashWithIndifferentAccess` which automatically converts symbol indexes into strings.

Quite often in Rails you'll encounter `HashWithIndifferentAccess` instances.  A perfect example is the params variable you access in your controller and view code.

Try using `work_effort.attributes.with_indifferent_access[key]`

Really it is just doing the same thing that you are, but it does it behind the scenes.

Comment: It works but is there any reason I should not use key.to_s or is the compelling argument that most everybody uses with_indifferent_access ?

Comment: I would just use key.to_s unless I had a very compelling reason not too.  In your case it appears that key.to_s is actually cheaper than with_indifferent_access

Answer (score 8):

You can overwrite the attributes method with your own.

Open your WorkEffort class

```
class WorkEffort
  def attributes
    super.symbolize_keys
  end
end
```

then when you call work_effort.attributes, you will have symbolized keys in the hash.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use : stringify_keys! which is extensively used all over Rails code.

```
def rollup_ancestor_updates(work_effort, ancestor_rollup_fields)
  ancestor_rollup_fields.stringify_keys!.each do |key, value|
    model_val = work_effort.attributes[key]
  end
  #....
end
```

Comment: How can this be dropped into my code example to get it to work without using key.to_s ?  Thanks; in the meantime I'm checking into the other example (with_indifferent_access which now I recall seeing in other places).

Comment: I think you should have said `symbolize_keys!`.  This idea is better than calling `with_indifferent_access` because it doesn't create a new Hash.  Unless, of course, you need to use both string and symbol keys.

Answer (score 1):

All of your Rails models can have symbolized attribute names:

```rb
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...

  class << self
    def attribute_names(symbols = false)
      return self.attribute_names.map(&:to_sym) if symbols

      super()
    end
  end
end
```

Then you can call `MyModel.attribute_names(symbols = true)` and get back `[:id, :my_attribute, :updated_at, :created_at, ...]` while still allowing `attribute_names` to return strings.

Note that [you need the parentheses after `super`](https://www.ruby-forum.com/t/calling-super-with-no-arguments/132522/2) to avoid an argument error with the originally defined function.